# Answer was deleted but the reputation was not reduced

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I deleted this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2551808/184968 a few days ago but my reputation was not reduced after that. I waited for a few days and did not see any reduction in my reputation.  Why deleting an answer does not result in reducing the reputation in this case?

Today I undeleted this answer and then deleted it again. Still the reputation has not been reduced.

Comment: wait for your reputation to be recalculated.

Comment: Already waited for a few days

Comment: Go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation and click on `Trigger Reputation Recalc`. And search for answer id (i.e. 2551808). And see if you have gained any reputation for that.

Comment: Did ever _gain_ reputation for the answer? If the upvotes happened _after_ hitting the reputation cap that day, a deletion of the answer will not incur reputation reduction. Alternatively, if you got rep from it but also enough upvotes on other questions on those days over the reputation cap, those upvotes will cover you.

Comment: @hims056. Did "Rep recalc". Still see points gained for this answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> answered Mar 31 '10 at 9:38

You answered the question nearly two years ago.

Reputation from posts that have a score of 3+ and are older than 60 days is not removed when the post is deleted.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra - It's not particularly new (I'm searching for the reference)

Comment: Why not removed, by the way?

Comment: @skwllsp - because when the instant rep removal for deleted posts came in those people who hadn't recalculated their reputation in 3 years suddendly "lost" a load of reputation that they didn't really have and whinged about it.

Comment: @ChrisF: references: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that `->` http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/

Comment: @Mat - thanks. I was having trouble finding them.